# Is there a proof of the following statement?

Tags: voltage, capacitor, circuit-analysis, current

I am reading ***Electronic Principles by P.E. Gray and C.L. Searle*** and I came across the following statement.

> If there are n capacitors
>   and no capacitor loops, the highest power of s in the characteristic equation
>   is n

Is there a proof of the following statement? and also what is meant in a capacitor loop?

Comment: This seems to be a round-about way of saying that an n-th order circuit has a characteristic equation of order n, no?

Comment: @Hearth I was looking to understand more why a circuit with n capacitors (provided there are no capacitor loops) will have a characteristic equation with degree n?

Comment: What level of proof do you need? It's easy enough to demonstrate by induction. There's an unstated assumption that the circuit contains only resistors and capacitors, no inductors. With zero capacitors, there's no frequency dependence, so s^0, with one there's s^1 and so on, it's almost a tautology, every time you add one capacitor, it's easy to find a configuration which increases the power of s by one, and no more.

Comment: I'm not seeing something here - how do you get a 2nd order circuit (I assume that means a 2nd order differential equation), with 2 capacitors and nothing else? Perhaps it's something to do with 'capacitor loops' (what are they?).

Comment: @Chu the statement is not mentioning other components, but neither any (wired) connection. Since the latter obviously needs to be assumed (in order to form loops), I think the first needs to be assumed as well.

Comment: @Huisman do you mean we have to assume other components? That seems a bit arbitrary. If we have two inductors in addition to the two capacitors then we have a 4th order TF. I think the context of the quote needs clarifying.

Comment: @Chu Yes, I think one should assume more components. And then, yes, you're definitely right regarding having inductors as well: the quote needs more context.

Answer (score 1):

The book can be found on: https://mirror.thelifeofkenneth.com/lib/electronics_archive/GraySearle-ElectronicPrinciples_text.pdf

On page 556 in PDF / page 553 in book, the section starts with:

> To find the general relationship between a<sub>1</sub>/a<sub>0</sub> and the network elements, we consider a linear active network that contains n capacitors and **no other 
>   energy storage**.
>   For simplicity, we develop the relation for a<sub>1</sub>/a<sub>0</sub> for the three- 
>   capacitor network of Fig. 15.3a, recognizing that **the PROOF can be readily 
>   generalized**.

This generalization of the proof can be demonstrate by induction, as @Neil_UK suggests, by adding another capacitor in Figure 15.3 and appending the equation for the next capacitor to eq. 15.23a and following equations.